# Windows 10 PC breaks whole network

Tags: networking, windows-10

Just installed Windows 10 on a new desktop PC. When it boots, the whole network crashes and no one has access to the internet, DNS requests fail and no traceroute beyond the main router.

LAN works OK and I can access the router web server and other LAN servers without problem.

When I disconnect this PC from the network, the next second everything works perfectly.

The same PC works OK on another network, and the same ethernet port and cable works OK with another PC.

Tried to update network drivers without solution. What to do next?

Comment: What else is on the network? What is running on the Windows 10 PC? Can the Windows 10 PC access the internet?

Comment: Have you given this PC its own static IP address? Sounds like it is having the same IP address as one of the routers or other network related unit.

Comment: Some Windows 7, 10 and Ubuntu PCs, one Windows Server, 6 printers and multimachines, 3 Raspberry Pi, and some smartphone and tablets. Only TeamViewer is installed. It can't access the Internet and no one else until I unplug the ethernet cable. On another network it works ok. On the same ethernet port and cable, another pc works ok.

Comment: Static IP and not on DHCP's range, no results. Manual DNS also.

Comment: A similar problem occurred on a network I used when a PC had the wrong TCP/IP packet type set. Check the *Network Properties* and compare to another Window 10 PC,  If it is not obvious, use a network sniffer to see what the PC is doing.

Comment: Do you mean _Network adapter properties_ or is it something else I don't know about?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Check for duplicate IP address and oddly enough, duplicate MAC addresses even though it's states that this isn't supposed to occur, I've heard of stories where it has happened with a NIC manufacturer hard-coding duplicate MAC addresses. Get the MAC from the machine while offline, and then start looking at arp tables or like do the Wireshark traces, etc. as suggested to see the traffic at the packet level. Obviously when connected it is conflicting with something on the network so pick a time when the network can be safely hosed up, and then do a trace (that machine & potentially another too).